# AnsgularJS - modelService unable to close first dialogue box

Tags: angularjs, model

I have a generic modelService to open dialogue boxes and to handle any click event raised from  dialogue box.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Open Login-panel as 1st dialogue box
2. Then from Login panel open forgot password dialgue box
3. Now Close the forgot password dialogue box,
   this works fine!
4. Now try to close 1st popup  (Login dialogue), nothing happens!
   even though associated event close gets triggered. ANd there
   are no errors being raised :(

Any suggestion what Am I missing here will be great.

**Source Code:**

modelService:

```
/**
 * This is replicating some of the confirm functionality, which isn't ideal.
 * @todo refactor confirm service to use this.
 */

myApp.factory('modalService', function ($compile, $templateCache, $http, $location, $store, safeApply, $timeout) {

    var modalService = {
        popup: {},
        templates: [],
        linkers: []
    };

    /**
     * Everything ready - show the modal
     */
    modalService.showModal = function (template, scope) {

        /**
         * Need to store linker
         * @see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1700
         */
        if (!this.linkers[template]) {
            this.linkers[template] = $compile(this.templates[template], scope);
        }
        this.popup = this.linkers[template](scope);

        $('body').append(this.popup)
            .show();

        if (this.popup.find('.lnk-cancel, .back-link')) {
            this.popup.find('.lnk-cancel, .back-link').on('click', function (e) {
                if (modalService.options.cancel) {
                    modalService.options.cancel();
                }
                modalService.closePopup();
                //e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    };

    /**
     * Close the modal
     */
    modalService.closePopup = function () {
        if (this.popup.remove) {
            this.popup.remove();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Create the actual content of the modal
     *
     * @param msg
     * @param templateUrl
     * @param scope
     */
    modalService.createModal = function (template, scope) {

        var self = this;

        scope.frameSrc = this.options.frameSrc;
        scope.title = this.options.title;
        scope.returnLink = this.options.returnLink || $store.get('locationstore.returnTo') || $location.path();
        scope.modalService = modalService;

        /*
         * Get the template an compile it
         */
        //if ( !this.templates[template] ) {
        var templatePromise = $http.get(template, { cache: $templateCache })
            .then(function (response) {
                self.templates[template] = response.data;
                self.showModal(template, scope);
            });
    };
    /*
     * Public methods
     */
    return {

        /**
         * Show a modal confirm
         *
         * @param msg
         * @param scope
         * @param options
         */
        show: function (popupName, template, scope, options) {

            safeApply(scope, function () {
                scope.name = popupName;
                modalService.options = options;
                modalService.createModal(template, scope);
            });
        },

        close: function (scope) {
            safeApply(scope, function () {
                modalService.closePopup();
            });
        }
    };

});
```

Login Panel:

```
<div class="modal-table">
  <div class="modal-table-cell">
    <div class="underlay  close-modals"></div>

    <div class="modal modal--medium login"  ng-controller="loginController">
        <div class="scroll-panel">
            <h1 class="modal__title">Login</h1>            
            <a class="back-link" href ng-click="returnTo(cancelLink)">Close</a>
        <div class="primary">
            <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="login()" >

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span class="error help-inline" ng-show="submitted && loginForm.email.$error.required">Please enter your email</span>
                        <input class="login__input" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" ng-model="email" id="login-email">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="error help-inline" ng-show="submitted && loginForm.password.$error.required">Please enter your password</span>
                        <input class="login__input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="login-password" ng-model="password" >
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div style="">
                <button class="login-button button main-button" style="min-width: 180px; max-width: 180px;padding-right: 50px; padding-left: 50px;" type="submit" id="login-submit">Login
                            <i   class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="showLoginProgress"></i>
                </button>
                </div>
                <a class="forgotten-pw" ng-click="resetPassword()" id="login-reset-password">Forgotten password</a>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <p>New users register now to</p>            
            <a class="action" ng-click="register()" id="login-register">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Popup-opening code snippets:

```
//Login Popup Show
   modalService.show('login-Popup', 'js/partials/loginPanel.html', $rootScope, {});

//Forgot Password Popup show 
    $scope.resetPassword = function () {
            //show: function (popupName, template, scope, options) {
            modalService.show('forgot-password', 'js/partials/iframeModal.html', $scope, {
                frameSrc: authnHost + '/resetPassword',
                title: "Forgotten password"
            });
        };
```

thanks

Login Panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
    $modalStack.dismissAll(reason);
```

this will close all the modal popup's

Comment: thanks for yor response @entre, I had fixed issue some other way but this seem useful to know.